# Tensorflow toco cannot convert graph.pb to graph.lite for tflite Android

Tags: android, tensorflow

I have trained the dataset using mobilenet_1.0_224 to produce the model file(.pb extension). I would like to use TFLite to develop an Android image recognition application. However, when I try to use toco to optimize the model to .lite extension, this error has been generated. I do not use the bazel-build because no matter how i try to install it, the bazel could not recognise my input file, which is the `graph.pb`. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Optimizing script used:

```
toco \
>   --input_file=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
>   --output_file=tf_files/optimized_graph.lite \
>   --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
>   --output_format=TFLITE \
>   --input_shape=1,${IMAGE_SIZE},${IMAGE_SIZE},3 \
>   --input_array=input \
>   --output_array=final_result \
>   --inference_type=FLOAT \
>   --input_type=FLOAT
```

Error generated:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python36\Scripts\toco.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.lite.toco.python'
```

Comment: have you specified the IMAGE_SIZE?

Comment: Have you built the freeze graph and toco tools as documented here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite

Failing that you'll need to specify your IMAGE_SIZE too